# In a Tale of Two Cities, Dickens says "in short, the period was so far like the present period" in the first paragraph of the first chapter

Tags: literature, charles-dickens

What does he mean? Does he mean that the periods were very different, or very similar?

Comment: "so far" means "up to this point".

Answer (score 4):

As Hot Licks said, "so far" often means "up to this point".  But I do not think that is the meaning in this Dickens quote.  I think "so far" followed by "that" means "so much" in this quote.

*A* was so far like *B* that *C*

meaning

*A* was so much like *B* that *C*

[The *Oxford English Dictionary* (under *so*) has a separate subitem for "*so far* followed by *that*".  But their examples of this usage are all from before 1900.]

Answer (score 1):

In the phrase **so far like** as it is used in the 19th century the word  *far*  retains the notion of extent or degree which the word **much** might not convey. I would paraphrase **so far** as "to that degree" or "to such a degree".  The full phrase **so far like** wants a content clause complement declaring a fact showing the extent of the comparison.

> Then was made a heaven, and angels were formed to people it. They are so far like God that they are intelligent and holy ; their nature is, moreover, *spiritual*

*The Evangelical Witness and Presbyterian Review*. Belfast, 1865.

To what extent are angels like God?  To the extent that they are intelligent and holy; moreover, their nature is spiritual.